# In wicket, combine wicket:link with IAuthorizationStrategy

Tags: java, authorization, wicket

I use an [`IAuthorizationStrategy`](http://wicket.apache.org/docs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/authorization/IAuthorizationStrategy.html) in wicket to limit access to certain pages. However, I also use html menus like this one:

```
<div class="siteMenu">
<wicket:link>
    <a href="Page1.html" class="siteMenuLink">
        <wicket:message key="pages.page1.title" />
    </a>
    <a
        href="Page2.html" class="siteMenuLink">
        <wicket:message key="pages.page2.title" />
    </a>
    <a
        href="Page3.html" class="siteMenuLink">
        <wicket:message key="pages.page3.title" />
    </a>
</wicket:link>
</div>
```

, that are automatically picked up and expanded using the `wicket:link` mechanism (like here: http://wicket.apache.org/examplenavomatic.html ). However, the `IAuthorizationStrategy` may not allow one or more of these target pages, so I may end up either with lots of links that lead to "permission denied" pages or lots of deactivated links (i.e. *em* tags or the like), neither of which is pretty.

I could of course write an [`IComponentInstantiationListener`](http://wicket.apache.org/docs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/application/IComponentInstantiationListener.html) that checks all `BookmarkableLinks` to see whether their target is accessible through the `IAuthorizationStrategy` and renders them invisible otherwise, but I wonder if there is an out-of-the-box solution to this problem. For clarification: I only use the [`isInstantiationAuthorized()`](http://wicket.apache.org/docs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/authorization/IAuthorizationStrategy.html#isInstantiationAuthorized(java.lang.Class%29) method of `IAuthorizationStrategy`.

Comment: @esko: thanks for editing, I didn't know about embedded links yet.

Comment: No prob :) Remember, this site is built by programmers for programmers, there's a lot of nifty features underneath the basic skin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, I was blind. The answer is obvious. Extend the authorization strategy to check the links to the pages and then use an [`IUnauthorizedComponentInstantiationListener`](http://wicket.apache.org/docs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/authorization/IUnauthorizedComponentInstantiationListener.html) to render them invisible

Comment: Any chance you can post some samples of what you did?  Would help others like me get a head start, as I think you are attempting exactly what I am after.

Comment: Sire, I'll do it from the office tomorrow.

Comment: OK, I created a project at http://code.google.com/p/wicket-component-auth/ you can either just grab the code or sign up and help me make it better

Comment: I will, heading over there now to check it out.